# How to identify a panoramic 360 degree image

Tags: c#, three.js, bitmapimage

Is there any method or technique to identify a bitmap (png/jpeg) is actually a 360 degree panoramic image or a normal image. What is the mechanism to distinguish panoramic image from normal image in C# or Three.js.

Comment: I would think one could do some pattern matching / correlation between the left and right edges of the photograph. If they are substantially similar, it *might* imply that the camera rotated all the way around. However, this would probably also flag a lot of typical panoramic shots (e.g. ocean horizon)

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: This is complex and error not dependable (implementation is not tough as we can easy do this matching using OPENCV). Is there any other method or parameter?

Comment: If I knew of anything else, I would have mentioned it.

Comment: Hope I can find an expert here...

Comment: Hi @Razack, I know its over 2 years later, but did you ever get a solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No solutions we tried later as we asked the user to input, when uploading an image. Comparing the ends slices is the option but not fool proof

Comment: Do you know of any way to bump up this Stack Overflow question? Or should I possibly just ask it again? I'm wondering if a couple years later anyone has come up with a more reliable method

Answer (score 5):

The ratio of the image has to be 2:1, for example, if your image width is 6000px and height 3000px, this is 360 images... in another words, calculate like this:

`var width  = 6000; var height = 3050; var ratio  = width/2; if(ratio >= height){ return 'This is 360 image';}else{ return 'This is not 360 image';}`

But this is just Client side solution, not sure if it will work for you, but i think Facebook have same solution. You can check Facebook website, and see how they do it, here your link:
https://facebook360.fb.com/editing-360-photos-injecting-metadata/

If you have access to the server side or you using server application(php,asp,coldfusion etc), you can check for meta tags, the 360 image should contain "XMP GPano Tags". You can use also a good online tool to check the meta tags for GPano for testing:
https://www.thexifer.net/#xmp-gpano-tags